# How to patch an attribute in an object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

The question is how to patch an attribute of an instance within a `with` statement. I tried with following example which doesn't work. It prints  as in the comment.

```
from mock import patch, PropertyMock

class Foo(object):
    f = {'a': 1}

new_foo = Foo()

with patch.object(new_foo, 'f', new_callable=PropertyMock) as mock:
    mock.return_value = {'b': 2}
    print new_foo.f
    # <PropertyMock name='f' id='4474801232'>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's an example in the [documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.PropertyMock).  You need to provide the class to patch.object, not the instantiated object.

```
from mock import patch, PropertyMock

class Foo(object):
    f = {'a': 1}

new_foo = Foo()

with patch.object(Foo, 'f', new_callable=PropertyMock) as mock:
    mock.return_value = {'b': 2}
    print new_foo.f

print new_foo.f
```

Outputs:

```
{'b': 2}
{'a': 1}
```

Comment: Actually the documentation you linked to uses `patch`, not `patch.object`. It's not really clear from that documentation when `patch` should be used vs. `patch.object`.

Answer (score 6):

`config.py`

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.greeting = "hola"
```

`test_first_test.py`

```
from config import myClass

@patch.object(myClass, "greeting", "what up homie")
def test_one(self):
    print(myClass.greeting)
```

Output:

`what up homie`

Comment: This one worked for me and it's very simple to implement. I think there should be an example like this in the documentation. Thanks!